# Overloading subtraction operator cpp

Tags: c++

I'm a bit new to object oriented programming in c++ and I've been trying to overload subtraction(-) operator in c++ for a Complex class I created. It is working fine except my program is terminating abnormally.
Below is what I've been trying to do:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
class Complex{
    //Data-members
private:
    int re, im;

    //methods
public:
    //Constructor
    Complex(){ /*default Constructor*/ }
    Complex(const int& re_, const int& im_):re(re_), im(im_){}
    //Subtraction(-) operator overloading
    Complex operator-(const Complex& op)
    {
        Complex res(this->re - op.re, this->im - op.im);
        return res;
    }
    //get-set methods for re
    int getReal(){ return re; }
    void setReal(const int& re){ this->re = re; }
    //get-set methods for im
    int getImaginary(){ return im; }
    void setImaginary(const int& im){ this->im = im; }
    //Destructor
    ~Complex(){ free(this); }
};

int main()
{
    Complex a(2, 3), b(3, 5);
    Complex d = a - b;
    std::cout<<"d.re = "<<d.getReal()<<" d.im = "<<d.getImaginary()<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please explain the cause of error.

Comment: What `free(this);` is supposed to do? It's unnecessary and causes the error.

Comment: Also, why pass `const int&` instead of a plain `int`?

Comment: Remove the `free(this)` from the destructor.   Calling `free()` with an argument that was not returned by `malloc()` (or related functions, like `calloc()` or `realloc()`) gives undefined behaviour.   There is nothing in your code returned by `malloc()`, and doesn't need to be.

Comment: See also *rule of three* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34740363/509868)

Comment: @anatolyg - rule of zero is more applicable here.   The class doesn't explicitly manage any resource, compiler-supplied default implementations of copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor are fine.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat using const int& copies reference and makes variable read only. Hence, consuming less memory and avoiding any change to the variable

Comment: @user9999486 "_Hence, consuming less memory_" Please show me example of system, where it would consume less memory. I, personally, cannot think of the use cases where it would consume less memory, while, simultaneously, I can think of cases, where it consumes more memory (64-bit systems, having 32-bit `int`s). 2) "_and avoiding any change to the variable_" Since the value would be passed by value, any changes you do, would be local to the function. Even if you want to disallow that, `const int` would accomplish the same.

Answer (score 4):

Never ever do `free(this)`, least of all in the destructor. The memory for the objects will be free'd outside of the destructor, either by the compiler generated code or by the user doing `delete` or `delete[]`.

In fact this is the cause of your problem, as the objects created never were allocated with `malloc`.

The proper solution in this case is to not only remove the `free` call, but the whole destructor, since it's not needed for this class.

Comment: using delete is also terminating the program abnormally.

Comment: @user9999486 `delete` must match a `new`, a `delete[]` must match a `new[]`. Nowhere in your code do you use `new`, so there shouldn't be any `delete`. As I said, it will be done automatically by the compiler since it is the compiler that allocates the objects.

Comment: @user9999486 No, not in this example anyway.

Comment: how do we know that we need to add an explicit destructor in a class

Comment: @user9999486 If your class obtain a resource of any kind, then you need to release it in the destructor. Lets say your constructor allocates memory (explicitly using `new`) then that memory must be deallocated, typically in a destructor.

Comment: @user9999486 "_how do we know that we need to add an explicit destructor in a class_" Example class, where one would need destructor: `class A {int* p; A (): p (new int) {} ~A() {delete p;}};` Note: `p` might be resource of any kind, which might need to be freed.